# Not always receiving json messages from elm-make with --report-json flag

Tags: json, elm, elm-make

I am trying to use the `--report=json` feature of **elm-make** to receive parseable error messages about the source files. Though it seems that **elm-make** doesn't always report errors in json, even with the proper flag. I experimented with using `elm-make --report=json Main.elm` with the below file

```
module Main exposing (..)

import Html Fxposing (..)

main : Html
main = text "Test"
```

It errors on `Fxposing` but doesn't return json, it returns the message below, which **flycheck-elm** cannot parse.

```
-- SYNTAX PROBLEM ----------------------------------------------------- Main.elm

I need a fresh line to start a new declaration. This means a new line that
starts with stuff, not with spaces or comments.

3| import Html Fxposing (..)
               ^
I am looking for one of the following things:

    reserved word `as`
    reserved word `exposing`
    whitespace
```

Is this an **elm-make** issue?

Comment: Probably. Does it never give JSON? Or is it inconsistent? If it's inconsistent, it's probably a bug.

Comment: @jmite It returns json for some types of error message and not for others.